# How to tell if a composite boson field should be real or complex?

Tags: field-theory, fermions, complex-numbers, grassmann-numbers

Let's say I have a system with two species of fermions, $f$ and $c$, where $f$'s are neutral but $c$'s are charged. Each of these has its own $U(1)$ related to particle-number conservation.

Now, if I consider an object $\phi = c^\dagger f$, I expect that this is bosonic because it is the product of fermion operators.

I know that $f$ and $c$ should both be described by Grassmann fields (say, $\bar{c}$ and $c$, $\bar{f}$ and $f$) in the continuum limit. But what about $\phi$? Should this be a complex- or real-valued field? I might think it should be real-valued because the total $U(1)$ particle number charge is 0, but I might also think it should be complex-valued because it has total $U(1)$ electric charge. How can I figure this out in a principled way?

Comment: So you have two commuting U(1)s: total fermion number and a "charge" with opposite eigenvalues on each fermion. $\phi$ is a doubly charged boson on that.

Answer (score 1):

Since $c^{\dagger}$ is Grassmann-odd complex [supernumber](https://planetmath.org/supernumber) and $f$ is an independent Grassmann-odd supernumber, it follows that $\phi = c^\dagger f$ is a nilpotent Grassmann-even complex supernumber. (The main point is that the complex phase doesn't cancel among independent factors.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this terminology. What do you mean by "Grassman-even/odd supernumber"? I think I understand the statement that, generically the $c$ and $f$ phases should not cancel, so $\phi$ will still be a complex-valued object.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!